# Deep Copying of a JavaScript Object not working when encapsulated within a VueJS computed property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, deep-copy

I have a JavaScript object in a Vue instance that is being deep copied into another JavaScript object via a computed property. However for some reason it shallow copies the object in question instead of a deep copy, even though `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` is being used:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="6">
        <v-text-field 
          v-model="formDialog.inputs.definition.val" 
          placeholder="Definition from FormDialog"></v-text-field>  
      </v-col>  
      <v-col cols="6">
        <v-text-field 
          v-model="initFields.definition" 
          placeholder="Definition from Init Fields"></v-text-field>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="6">
        <v-text-field 
          v-model="formDialog.inputs.synonym.val" 
          placeholder="Synonym from FormDialog"></v-text-field>
      </v-col>  
      <v-col cols="6">
        <v-text-field 
          v-model="initFields.synonym" 
          placeholder="Synonym from Init Fields"></v-text-field>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
   
  </v-app>
</div>
```

I am attempting to deep copy the value of `formDialog.inputs` using the following loop within a compupted property:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      formDialog: {
                    inputs: {
                        definition: {
                            val: '', save: true, add: true,
                            icon: 'mdi-file-word',
                            placeholder: 'Word Definition'
                        },

                        synonym: {
                            val: '', save: true, add: true,
                            placeholder: 'Synonyms'
                        }
                    }
                }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    initFields: function() {
      let obj = {};
      if(typeof this.formDialog.inputs != 'undefined') {
        for(let key of Object.keys(this.formDialog.inputs)) {
          if(typeof this.formDialog.inputs[key].val != 'undefined') {
            //obj[key] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.formDialog.inputs[key]));
            obj[key] = this.formDialog.inputs[key].val;
          }
        }
      }

      return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
      //return obj;
    }  
  }
})
```

However the `obj` object is retaining a shallow copy of the `this.formDialog.inputs` object, when I expect it to make a deep copy of it. Why is it not creating a deep copy of the object even though I am using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`?

Demonstration of issue:
https://codepen.io/deftonez4me/pen/qBapYgP

Comment: What is your reasoning that this is a shallow copy? Creating a new object from a string using `JSON.parse` could not possibly lead to a shallow copy. Not that I not believe you, I would be as baffled as you, I'm sure. I'm just curious how you confirm that your copy is actually shallow.

Comment: Note that all of the `val` property values are the empty string, so calling `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(''))` returns the empty string, or the same value as a shallow copy...

Comment: The elements in the `obj` object are still retaining the reference to the elements of `this.formDialog.inputs`. When I modify `this.formDialog.inputs` it also modifies the `obj` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a somewhat abridged version of your code, which, I believe will serve our purpose:

```js
const formDialog = {
    inputs: {
        id: {
            val: '',
            save: true,
        },

        word_data: [],

        definition: {
            val: '',
                save: true, add: true,
                icon: 'mdi-file-word',
                placeholder: 'Word Definition'
        },

        synonym: {
            val: '', save: true, add: true,
                placeholder: 'Synonyms'
        }
    }
}

let obj = {};
for(let key of Object.keys(formDialog.inputs)) {
    if(typeof formDialog.inputs[key].val !== 'undefined') {
        //why is this line making a shallow copy and not a deep copy?
        obj[key] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(formDialog.inputs[key]));
    }
}

obj.id.val = 'zunit';

console.log(obj);

console.log(formDialog)
```

Notice that I have made a correction to your loop by knocking off the `val` before feeding it into `JSON.stringify`. You mention that

> The elements in the obj object are still retaining the reference to the elements of this.formDialog.inputs. When I modify this.formDialog.inputs it also modifies the obj elements

But I'm afraid that's not true as you will see by changing `obj.id.val` of the cloned object, the original object is unaffected.

So outside of that tweak, your code works fine. Perhaps your specific environment creates the issue as you do appear to be doing this inside a class.

Comment: That does not work for me either. It's possible it's an issue specific to the frameworks I am using. It's within a computed property in a vueJS component. I'll create a snippet and recreate the environment i'm developing it in.

Comment: I added a Codepen demonstration of what i am referring to. https://codepen.io/deftonez4me/pen/qBapYgP

Answer (score -1):

You should try this:

```
    if (this.formDialog.hasOwnProperty('inputs')) {
        obj[key] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.formDialog.inputs));
    }
```